# File1 + (File2 - first line) > File3

Tags: unix, sed, cat

I have two csv/text files that I'd like to join. Both contain the same first line. I'm trying to figure out how to use sed and cat to produce a merged file, but with only one copy of the first line. And I'm having a time with syntax. Any help would be greatly appreciated :-D!
Thanks,
Andrew

Answer (score 4):

This will combine files `data1.txt` and `data2.txt` in file `merged.txt`, skipping the first line from `data2.txt`. It uses awk if you are ok with it:

```
(cat data1.txt; awk 'NR>1' data2.txt) > merged.txt
```

awk appends all lines with line number > 1 from file `data2.txt` to file `merged.txt`.

`NR` is a built-in awk variable that stands for the current line number of the file being processed. If the Boolean expression `NR > 1` is true, awk prints the line implicitly.

If you didn't care about keeping `data1.txt` intact, you could just append your 2nd file (minus its first line) and reduce to just this:

```
awk 'NR>1' data2.txt >> data1.txt
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `tail -n +2` instead of `awk 'NR > 1'`.

Comment: @TannerL.Swett Neat .. I was thinking first of using `head` or `tail` somehow, but I was certain on how to do this with `awk`. And of course if OP didn't care about keeping `data1.txt` the solution could skip the first command and just append the 2nd file (-the first line) to that file.

Answer (score 4):

Another option with awk:

```
awk 'NR==FNR || FNR>1' file1.txt file2.txt .. fileN.txt
```

This prints all lines in the first file, OR any line in subsequent files after the first line.

Comment: what would happen if I did this: `awk 'NR==FNR || FNR>1' *.txt`

Comment: You would rely on the order of files that were matched by the file globbing.  If they all contain identical first lines, then this should be safe.  Why don't you try it and see what happens?

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the most straightforward solution is:

```
( cat file1.txt ; tail -n +2 file2.txt ) > file3.txt
```

It has the advantage of stating clearly just what you're doing: print the entire first file, then print all but the first line of the second file, writing the output to the third file.

Answer (score 1):

solved with one line
   '1 d' means to delete first line in file2

the following command will append the result to file1

```
sed '1 d' file2 >> file1
```

Comment: You are modifying both `file1` and `file2` with this command - this may or may not be ok with OP. Better to provide both options (the other one being not changing either of the original files).

Comment: @Levon: no, you are not modifying `file2` here.

Comment: @tripleee Just tested it, it doesn't *delete* but rather doesn't *display* the first line .. got it. Could probably be phrased better in the answer though.